# Is there a word for "extreme feminism"?

Tags: single-word-requests, gender-politics

*Feminism* is defined as

> Feminism is a collection of movements aimed at defining, establishing, and defending equal political, economic, and social rights for women.

in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feminism) and

> A social theory or political movement supporting the equality of both sexes in all aspects of public and private life; specifically, a theory or movement that argues that legal and social restrictions on females must be removed in order to bring about such equality.

in [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/feminism).
Masculism is defined as the exact same but with equality for men's rights, which actually means the same.

I think that this is in fact a wrong use of the word *feminism* which puts emphasis on the word women (~ Latin *femina*) instead of equality between sexes.

I'm looking for a word that represents a movement which can be assumed and extremist feminism and that supports more or better rights for women above men. Or just supporting more women's rights regardless of those of men. This is what I would think of when hearing *feminism*, until I discovered this wasn't true.

Comment: I don't think you can define feminism quite so easily.  To my mind this is more of a politics question.  I'm sure you can find terms like *ultra-feminism* and so on, though they are most likely going to be considered pejorative by feminists.

Comment: I'm curious why you're looking for such a term.

Comment: The terms `Feminism` and `Masculism` cannot be defined as simple antonyms. Feminism has a long history fighting against male domination and for equality. Masculism in contrast does not fight against female domination as in  most societies there was and is no female domination.

Comment: @Jakob I'm aware of the fact that feminism is more than it's meaning. But nevertheless is it commonly defined the way I cited. Which is a very well description of the movement it originated from. Sadly only, pure etymologically, I think the word is not very suited for it's meaning. And in these modern times there are people using if for a more extreme way of thinking than the original meaning. But I think the word feminism is more suited for this this meaning than for it's original one. Etymologically.

Comment: Well, I would say that today's feminism is actually just that. Feminists tend to see their situation as overly male dominated, despite that often being a subjective feeling of their own, and seek to reduce the rights of males rather than aim for a balance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'd suggest **female chauvinism**.

Female chauvinism refers to the attitude that women are superior to men, and it has been used by critics of some aspects of feminism. This should be kept distinct from a similar but not identical concept of the term popularized by "Female Chauvinist Pigs: Women and the Rise of Raunch Culture" a book by Ariel Levy published in 2005.

More discussion is available in the **[Wikipedia article about female chauvinism and chauvinism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chauvinism#Female_chauvinism)** in general.

Comment: This is the best answer. It cites real sources, by women, who identify as feminists and identified by others as feminists. While there is still contention around both the term and its semantics it is a legitimate "term of art".

Answer (score 12):

A derisive term used by people to denigrate a person whose feminism is felt to be too extreme is **feminazi**.

**Female domination** or **female superiority** refers to the theory or state of women having authority over men.

**Matriarchy** refers to a social structure in which women dominate families and familial rights pass from mothers to daughters.

Comment: Ah, I know similar words like `gramar nazi's`. Can I refer to being a feminazi as `feminazism`?

Comment: @StevenRoose - Sure, use _feminazism_ but only if your purpose is to refer to the notion desparagingly.  Chaos has a good answer if your looking for a more formal, less value-laden term. (+1 for chaos, by the way).

Comment: @StevenRoose: It isn't a usual formation but people will get it.  If you want to be especially arch, consider *feminational socialism*.

Comment: @StevenRoose Might you mean `grammar` not "gramar"? As for `matriarchy`: That is a concept that predates feminism (or is it Feminism?) and isn't necessarily equivalent in any way to modern concepts of feminism. It can be a legal construct only  (or similar to ummm primogeniture, I think, but without any associated power).

Comment: This answer is even worse; "feminazi" is a derailing and dismissive term most often applied to women of an incredibly moderate feminism in an attempt to seek a false "middle ground" in a space that retains male superiority. (And "female domination" mostly commonly describes a type of BDSM scenario.)

Comment: *Amazon Women from the Moon*!

Comment: @JoeWreschnig I think I was looking for a term like feminazi. I was looking for women that demand all men's rights for women but without sacrificing any women's benefits. F.e. women claiming that a minimum of 50% women is required in a government, but 60% is no problem either. Or those thinking it's wrong that most domestic workers are women but having no problem with garbage collectors being all men.

Comment: 'Feminazi' might be exactly what you're looking for but it is considered somewhat derogatory and is often used as an insult to proponents of regular mainstream feminism. Why doesn't 'extreme feminism' work? (since it should capture the extreme elements that you're thinking of)

Comment: You were not looking for such women but for a term that is used to describe them. The term `feminazi` is only used as offense, not as description, as nobody would give himself this name.

Comment: @Steven: Bringing a term like "feminazi" into a serious discussion of modern gender issues is like trying to bring a term like "carpetbagger" into a serious discussion of modern race issues. You will be instantly (and rightly) written off as a crazy bigot. (Also: "I was looking for women that demand all men's rights for women but without sacrificing any women's benefits. F.e. women claiming that a minimum of 50% women is required in a government, but 60% is no problem either." The latter is not an example of the former.)

Comment: @Jakob I suppose you knew that that was what I meant saying?

Comment: @Mitch Yes actually I used 'extreme feminism' until now. I was just wondering if there was a common word for it I didn't knew.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig I'm aware of that. Therefore I was not considering using 'feminazi' in serious discussion, just for f.e. warning people calling themselves feminists but have more extreme opinions that they should not confuse feminism with their believes.
Your last remark, why aren't these examples? Because I used "sacrificing any women's benefits"? It's not a definition I use for it, just to give an example. Although "not being considered for garbage collector" can be considered a benefit.

Comment: What a terrible answer, and with 12 votes, too. "Feminazi" is a highly offensive and derogatory term to criticize the feminist movement. "Female domination" and "female superiority" are rarely used, except perhaps in BDSM contexts. And "matriarchy" is only used to describe actual matriarchal societies, or as an empowering term in comparison with "the patriarchy."

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to be instantly identifiable as a privileged male geek, I recommend **turbofeminist**. It is a recent coinage, but will instantly create the kind of strawman you want in the minds of others such as yourself, and likewise let decent people write you off just as quickly.

Comment: Turbofeminism produces 229 hits in Google and I can't find somewhat of a definition anywhere.

Comment: 229 hits in its three day existence is pretty good I think.

Comment: I can find mentions from <Jun 13th. Even some from 2010, but probably they refer to "becoming a feminist quickly". Still didn't find any definitions.

Comment: I like the tone of this answer, but not the actual suggestion, as I've never heard of it before.

Comment: @TRiG: It was used by a Kotaku commenter a few days ago while describing his outrage at the site giving the meagre scraps it does to gender equality (i.e. the same crap Steven is doing here). Some feminist game developers / critics on Twitter have taken it and run with it.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like the word "extreme feminism," I'd suggest **radical feminism** or **ultrafeminism**.

**Militant feminism** may be more controversial but suitable in certain contexts. A militant ideology or movement is defined by the Google Dictionary as being:

> combative and aggressive in support of a political or social cause, and typically favoring extreme, violent, or confrontational methods.

Answer (score 1):

Neo feminist is when a female assumes or believes that females should lead and be more dominant in work, life, etc. than men. It glorifies a womanly essence over claims to equality with men